# Arraylist is printing previously added elements along side newly added elements

Tags: java, arraylist

I want my arraylist to print elements like this:

1894,

1895,

1896,

etc..

but i am getting 1894, 1895, 1896

```
     ArrayList<Integer> years = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int j;

    for (j = 1894; j < 2014; j++)

    {
        years.add(j);
        //comboyears.addItem(j);

    }
    System.out.println(years);
```

Comment: Why would anyone downvote this question? It is a specific question and gives an example of the problem. It doesn't deserve a down-vote just because it is a beginner question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are actually printing `years`, which will print the `String` returned by the `toString()` of the `ArrayList`.

You are getting the array multiple times, because the `print` statement is inside the `for` loop, so each iteration it will print the array (with the element recently added). To print the array just one time, move the `print` outside the loop.

If you want to print each element without `[]` you could try the following:

```
for (Integer i : years) {
    System.out.print(i + ", "); // This will print a comma at the end
}
```

or this, to avoid printing an extra comma `,`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < years.size() - 1; i++) {
    System.out.print(years.get(i) + ", ");
}
System.out.println(years.get(years.size() - 1));
```

**Output:**

```
1894, 1895, 1896, 1897, 1898, 1899, 1900, 1901, 1902, 1903, 1904, ...
```

**Edit:**

You can also override the `toString` method while creating a new instance of `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<Integer> years = new ArrayList<Integer>()
{
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < size() - 1; i++) {
            sb.append(get(i));
            sb.append(", ");
        }
        sb.append(get(size() - 1));
        return sb.toString();
    }
};
```

So you can print the array `System.out.println(years);` in the way you want.

**Edit 2:**

Since you have edited the question, *which I would encourage you not to do*, you can do this adding a new-line character `\ n` or changing `print` by `println`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < years.size() - 1; i++) {
    System.out.println(years.get(i) + ", "); // or concatenate with ", \n"
}
System.out.println(years.get(years.size() - 1));
```

If you are overriding `toString` method from `ArrayList` you can append a new-line character too. Replace `sb.append(", ") with

```
sb.append(", \n")
```

Answer (score 4):

This is expected if you keep your `System.out.print` inside the `for` loop.  You are printing out the entire list every time you add an element.

If you only want to print it when you're done adding, move the `System.out.print` after the end of the `for` loop.

Comment: I have implemented the changes and it works! thanks! i have now edited the question could you please help me further?

Comment: You shouldn't edit the question, since all answers are based on the original one.

Comment: @user3198936 That's true i just recently read the question and i don't  understand why the answers are not related to the question!

Comment: @rgettman I have implemented the changes and it works! thanks! i have now edited the question could you please help me further?

Comment: You shouldn't edit the question; it's like a bait-and-switch.

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<Integer> years = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int j;

for (j = 1894; j < 2014; j++)
{
    years.add(j);
    System.out.println(years.get(j) + ","); // get elements from 1894 to 2014
}
```